# Insert click event inside one function with onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have one function for send message if the Enter is pressed. But, I created one button for send message too, and if I call this function, the message does not send, and I added the click event.

```
  function inputKeyDown(event, inputBox) {
    // Submit on enter key, dis-allowing blank messages
    if (event.keyCode === 13 && inputBox.value || event.onclick && inputBox.value) {            

      // Send the user message
      Api.sendRequest(inputBox.value, context);

      // Clear input box for further messages
      inputBox.value = '';
      Common.fireEvent(inputBox, 'input');
    }
  }
```

I try add one click event inside this if condition and does not work, I test the button with one alert event and works fine when I click.

**Check my html:**

```
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
          <input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
           placeholder="Type something" type="text"
           onkeydown="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">

            <button class="Testbutton" onclick="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">
              <i class="icon send"></i>
            </button>

 </label>
```

My function onkeydown works fine to send the message. But when I changed the function added one onclick event, my button doesn't work. I debugged the button with `alert` and work perfectly.

What am I doing wrong? Someone can help me please.

Comment: What is `Common`?

Comment: Is for send my message inside the input element. I'm using some API. My event to send works perfectly when I press enter. I just want send if user click in the button too.

Comment: what was your `onclick=`?

Comment: `<button class="Testbutton" onclick="alert('test')">` I try use the same function but does not work =\

Comment: if by same function you mean `ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)` then of course it won't work, because you need to pass input (2nd param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` condition needs adjustment. In order to check if the event was a click, you need to use `event.type === 'click'`. Also it can be simplified a bit by checking `inputBox.value` just once. I modified your `inputKeyDown` function:

```
function inputKeyDown(event, inputBox) {
    // Submit on enter key, dis-allowing blank messages
    if (inputBox.value && event.keyCode === 13 || event.type === 'click') {            

      // Send the user message
      Api.sendRequest(inputBox.value, context);

      // Clear input box for further messages
      inputBox.value = '';
      Common.fireEvent(inputBox, 'input');
    }
  }
```

Also, you need to pass the input element as the second parameter on the `onclick` handler:

```
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
          <input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
           placeholder="Type something" type="text"
           onkeydown="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">

            <button class="Testbutton" onclick="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, document.getElementById('textInput'))">
              <i class="icon send"></i>
            </button>

 </label>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank u!

Answer (score 2):

create a new function `sendMessage` then call it from different events like below.

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('textInput');

// for input keydown
function inputKeyDown(event) {
  // Submit on enter key, dis-allowing blank messages
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    sendMessage();
  }
}

// for button click
function sendMessage() {
  if (inputBox.value) {
    // Send the user message
    console.log(inputBox.value);
    Api.sendRequest(inputBox.value, context);

    // Clear input box for further messages
    inputBox.value = '';
    Common.fireEvent(inputBox, 'input');
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
  <input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
   placeholder="Type something" type="text"
   onkeydown="inputKeyDown(event)">
  <button class="Testbutton" onclick="sendMessage()">
    <i class="icon send"></i>Send
  </button>
</label>
```

Comment: Hey man, your example works too, but, in this case I needed use just the function inputKeyDown() because other business rules in my application. Thanks too! +1